# Build a Boolean function for the following logic statement

Tags: logic

I'd appreciate if somebody can shed some light on this. So far I've been able to do the homework about writing boolean functions for some logic statements, but I'm stuck with this:

> For two statements: If at least one of them is false, then true is
>   equal two one.

The wording of the last part got me puzzled. I asked my teacher and told me that the answer is

$$f(x,y) = (x|y) \to (x\oplus y)$$

but I don't understand where the Sheffer stroke comes from. From the first part of the sentence:

> If at least one of them is false...

my attempt was to write $x \vee y$.

With the second part of the statement I'm lost. So far I've been using $\oplus$ where I have expression like *''either...or..''*, but anything like the posing of the sentence above.

Answer (score 1):

The [Scheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) is the `NAND` operator. It returns `True` except when both are true. In other words, it returns `True` if at least one is false, which is why that's the first part.

The [exclsuive or $\oplus$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) is the `XOR` operator, but "true is equal two one" doesn't make any sense.

You can certainly write it without these fancy symbols since

$$x \mid y = \neg\,(x \wedge y)$$

and

$$x \oplus y = (x \vee y) \wedge \neg\,(x \wedge y) = (x \wedge \neg\,y) \vee (\neg\,x \wedge y)$$